# OnTap on the column(BarGraph) will take it to next screen iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, graph, charts

I have a simple requirement for plotting Bar graph with x-axis with 9 years and y-axis with annual expenses $200 then $400  then $600 and so on .OnTap on the year/column will take it to next screen with all details of expenses data.I have tried all charts like fusion,am,core plot but I am unable get this functionality and proceed.How to get this functionality.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a search engine or recommendation site. Google and Bing both excel at doing searches, and provide links to the results. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifically says that discussion and opinion type questions are a poor fit for the design here. Voting to close as not constructive. We'll be glad to help if you have specific questions once you've located the product you want to use and start writing code for it; just post the question with the code you've tried so far that isn't working and someone can probably help you figure out the problem.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your question mentioning the specific issue. If I am correct, your issue is the tap detection on click of a a barplot. Modify the title and question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [coreplot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) for this requirement. Use the below method to detect the tap on bar plot. Rest everything is possible with all the charting libraries. For more details check their [sample code CPTestApp](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CPTestApp/?r=edb524315bc6bf4d56d42646d1fd7dd1fe659ae4). Also [check this documentation.](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg-history/7888d057a237931fad47e264000e059326e31aa9/documentation/html/MacOS/protocol_c_p_t_bar_plot_delegate-p.html). Here is the [discussion on this in google forum.](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=168)

```
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex %d", index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ACB but I get error in coreplot xcode4.5 I know this is not the right place to ask question but even coreplot is not working,

Comment: @John Wood, What is the error you are getting. You can either raise a new question with that error. This is the right place to ask such question. Check here http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=168. I have updated answer. It should be CPTBarPlot and not CPBarPlot. That could be error you got.

Comment: How do I implement coreplot in the project Xcode 4.5 ios6

Comment: @JohnWood, Please check the sample code CPTestapp. The link is present in answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Helped me to do a pilot another query I had , how to have dynamic data in x-axis/y-axis in coreplot iOS :Currently using the demo code here:Below every column I need year on x-axis which itself is dynamic and y axis revenue amount .How do I do that dynamically? link to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756047/dynamic-data-in-coreplot-ios-on-x-axis-and-y-axis