# dynamic data in coreplot iOS on x-axis and y-axis

Tags: ios, graph, charts, ios6, core-plot

how to have dynamic data in x-axis/y-axis in coreplot iOS :Currently using the demo code here:Below every column I need year on x-axis which itself is dynamic  and y axis revenue amount .How do I do that dynamically?

```
    //
    //  CPDStockPriceStore.m
    //  CorePlotDemo
    //
    //  NB: Price data obtained from Yahoo! Finance:
    //  http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL
    //  http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOG
    //  http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=MSFT
    //
    //  Created by Steve Baranski on 5/4/12.
    //  Copyright (c) 2012 komorka technology, llc. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "CPDStockPriceStore.h"

    @interface CPDStockPriceStore ()


    @end

    @implementation CPDStockPriceStore

    #pragma mark - Class methods

    + (CPDStockPriceStore *)sharedInstance
    {
        static CPDStockPriceStore *sharedInstance;

        static dispatch_once_t once;
        dispatch_once(&once, ^{
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];      
        });

        return sharedInstance;
    }

    #pragma mark - API methods

    - (NSArray *)tickerSymbols
    {
        static NSArray *symbols = nil;
        if (!symbols)
        {
            symbols = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       @"AAPL", 
                       @"GOOG", 
                       @"MSFT", 
                       nil];
        }
        return symbols;
    }

    - (NSArray *)dailyPortfolioPrices
    {
        static NSArray *prices = nil;
        if (!prices)
        {
            prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:582.13], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:604.43], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.01], 
                      nil];
        }
        return prices;
    }

    - (NSArray *)datesInWeek
    {
        static NSArray *dates = nil;
        if (!dates)
        {
            dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"4/23", 
                     @"4/24", 
                     @"4/25",
                     @"4/26", 
                     @"4/27",                   
                     nil];
        }
        return dates;
    }

    - (NSArray *)weeklyPrices:(NSString *)tickerSymbol
    {
        if ([CPDTickerSymbolAAPL isEqualToString:[tickerSymbol uppercaseString]] == YES)
        {
            return [self weeklyAaplPrices];
        }
        else if ([CPDTickerSymbolGOOG isEqualToString:[tickerSymbol uppercaseString]] == YES)
        {
            return [self weeklyGoogPrices];
        }
        else if ([CPDTickerSymbolMSFT isEqualToString:[tickerSymbol uppercaseString]] == YES)
        {
            return [self weeklyMsftPrices];
        }
        return [NSArray array];
    }

    - (NSArray *)datesInMonth
    {
        static NSArray *dates = nil;
        if (!dates)
        {
            dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"2", 
                     @"3", 
                     @"4",
                     @"5",
                     @"9", 
                     @"10", 
                     @"11",
                     @"12", 
                     @"13",
                     @"16", 
                     @"17", 
                     @"18",
                     @"19", 
                     @"20", 
                     @"23", 
                     @"24", 
                     @"25",
                     @"26", 
                     @"27",
                     @"30",                   
                     nil];
        }
        return dates;
    }

    - (NSArray *)monthlyPrices:(NSString *)tickerSymbol
    {
        if ([CPDTickerSymbolAAPL isEqualToString:[tickerSymbol uppercaseString]] == YES)
        {
            return [self monthlyAaplPrices];
        }
        else if ([CPDTickerSymbolGOOG isEqualToString:[tickerSymbol uppercaseString]] == YES)
        {
            return [self monthlyGoogPrices];
        }
        else if ([CPDTickerSymbolMSFT isEqualToString:[tickerSymbol uppercaseString]] == YES)
        {
            return [self monthlyMsftPrices];
        }
        return [NSArray array];
    }

    #pragma mark - Private behavior

    - (NSArray *)weeklyAaplPrices
    {
        static NSArray *prices = nil;
        if (!prices)
        {
            prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:571.70], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:560.28], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:610.00], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:607.70], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:603.00],                   
                      nil];
        }
        return prices;
    }

    - (NSArray *)weeklyGoogPrices
    {
        static NSArray *prices = nil;
        if (!prices)
        {
            prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:597.60], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:601.27], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:609.72], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:615.47], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:614.98],                   
                      nil];
        }
        return prices;
    }

    - (NSArray *)weeklyMsftPrices
    {
        static NSArray *prices = nil;
        if (!prices)
        {
            prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.12], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.92], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.20], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.11], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.98],                   
                      nil];
        }
        return prices;
    }

    - (NSArray *)monthlyAaplPrices
    {
        static NSArray *prices = nil;
        if (!prices)
        {
            prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:618.63], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:629.32], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:624.31], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:633.68], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:636.23], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:628.44], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:626.20], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:622.77], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:605.23],
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:580.13], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:609.70], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:608.34], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:587.44], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:572.98],
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:571.70], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:560.28], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:610.00], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:607.70], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:603.00],
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:583.98],                  
                      nil];
        }
        return prices;
    }

    - (NSArray *)monthlyGoogPrices
    {
        static NSArray *prices = nil;
        if (!prices)
        {
            prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:646.92], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:642.62], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:635.15], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:632.32], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:630.84], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:626.86], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:635.96], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:651.01], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:624.60], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:606.07], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:609.57], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:607.45], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:599.30], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:596.06], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:597.60], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:601.27], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:609.72], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:615.47], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:614.98], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:604.85],                  
                      nil];
        }
        return prices;
    }

    - (NSArray *)monthlyMsftPrices
    {
        static NSArray *prices = nil;
        if (!prices)
        {
            prices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.29], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.94], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.21], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.52], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.10], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:30.47], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:30.35], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:30.98], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:30.81],
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.08], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.44], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.14], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.01], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.42],
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.12], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.92], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.20], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.11], 
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:31.98],  
                      [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:32.02],                  
                      nil];
        }
        return prices;
    }

@end




    #import "CPDBarGraphViewController.h"

    @interface CPDBarGraphViewController ()

    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView *hostView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CPTBarPlot *aaplPlot;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CPTBarPlot *googPlot;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CPTBarPlot *msftPlot;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *priceAnnotation;

    -(IBAction)aaplSwitched:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)googSwitched:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)msftSwitched:(id)sender;

    -(void)initPlot;
    -(void)configureGraph;
    -(void)configurePlots;
    -(void)configureAxes;
    -(void)hideAnnotation:(CPTGraph *)graph;

    @end



    @implementation CPDBarGraphViewController

    CGFloat const CPDBarWidth = 0.25f;
    CGFloat const CPDBarInitialX = 0.25f;

    @synthesize hostView    = hostView_;
    @synthesize aaplPlot    = aaplPlot_;
    @synthesize googPlot    = googPlot_;
    @synthesize msftPlot    = msftPlot_;
    @synthesize priceAnnotation = priceAnnotation_;

    #pragma mark - Rotation
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
    }

    #pragma mark - UIViewController lifecycle methods
    -(void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self initPlot];
    }




    #pragma mark - Chart behavior
    -(void)initPlot {
        self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = NO;
        [self configureGraph];
        [self configurePlots];
        [self configureAxes];    
    }

    -(void)configureGraph {
        // 1 - Create the graph
        CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
        graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
        self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;    
        // 2 - Configure the graph    
        [graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainBlackTheme]];    
        graph.paddingBottom = 30.0f;      
        graph.paddingLeft  = 30.0f;
        graph.paddingTop    = -1.0f;
        graph.paddingRight  = -5.0f;
        // 3 - Set up styles
        CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
        titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
        // 4 - Set up title
        NSString *title = @"Portfolio Prices: April 23 - 27, 2012";
        graph.title = title;  
        graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
        graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
        graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, -16.0f);
        // 5 - Set up plot space
        CGFloat xMin = 0.0f;
        CGFloat xMax = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInWeek] count];
        CGFloat yMin = 0.0f;
        CGFloat yMax = 800.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];
        plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax)];
    }

    -(void)configurePlots {
        // 1 - Set up the three plots
        self.aaplPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor redColor] horizontalBars:NO];
        self.aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
        self.googPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor] horizontalBars:NO];
        self.googPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolGOOG;
        self.msftPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
        self.msftPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolMSFT;
        // 2 - Set up line style
        CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
        barLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
        barLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;
        // 3 - Add plots to graph
        CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
        CGFloat barX = CPDBarInitialX;
        NSArray *plots = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.aaplPlot, self.googPlot, self.msftPlot, nil];
        for (CPTBarPlot *plot in plots) {
            plot.dataSource = self;
            plot.delegate = self;
            plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(CPDBarWidth);
            plot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromDouble(barX);
            plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
            [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
            barX += CPDBarWidth;
        } 
    }

    -(void)configureAxes {
        // 1 - Configure styles
        CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
        axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
        axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
        CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
        axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
        axisLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
        // 2 - Get the graph's axis set
        CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
        // 3 - Configure the x-axis
        axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
        axisSet.xAxis.title = @"Days of Week (Mon - Fri)"; 
        axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;    
        axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 10.0f;
        axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;    
        // 4 - Configure the y-axis
        axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
        axisSet.yAxis.title = @"Price";
        axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
        axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = 5.0f;      
        axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;        
    }

    -(void)hideAnnotation:(CPTGraph *)graph {
        if ((graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea) && (self.priceAnnotation)) {
            [graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea removeAnnotation:self.priceAnnotation];
            self.priceAnnotation = nil;
        }
    }

    #pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
    -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
        return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInWeek] count];
    }

    -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
        if ((fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip) && (index < [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInWeek] count])) {
            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL]) {
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] weeklyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] objectAtIndex:index];
            }   }
        return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index]; 
    }

    #pragma mark - CPTBarPlotDelegate methods
    -(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

         NSLog(@"barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex %d", index);
    }

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [another tutorial here](http://www.gilthonwe.com/2012/06/09/stacked-bar-chart-coreplot-ios/) that might help you.

Check 3. Layout of the graph, line 24. There he makes the Y axis dynamically, but it all depends how you make your datasource.

Hope it clears up :)

Comment: Glad it could help. I used it to maked stacked bar chart, really useful :)